# How to force one datasource to always load before another?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report with two datasources - a web service call, and a SQL Server Select.

The web service call populates a table in the database with data based on the parameters that the report was executed for. The select then retrieves this data.

Since the SQL Server select is dependent on the web service having run before it - how can I enforce this? Is there a way to force SSRS to always execute the web service data source *before* it tries to retrieve information from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to define the order of the datasource but the dataset execution.

Usually the datasets are run, depending on the order they are specified or used on the report.  But if you really want to specify causality on two datasets, just define an internal parameter that has its values from the webservice dataset, and then pass that parameter to the SQL dataset (you can put in on the query as `@param = @param` for example)

Comment: This unfortunately isn't a solution unless the query renders in <1s. The reason for this is that the query for the parameter will render pre-load with no feedback provided to the user (basically the browser will just hang, telling the user nothing)